# I can't figure out the point about the array name

Tags: c, arrays, implicit-conversion, rvalue, unary-operator

I've recently posted a few questions about array names here.

Thanks to a lot of people, now i know that the array name is not a pointer, and also know that the array name is an non-modifiable *l-value*.

I'm have one more question about array.

1. I was told that the array name is converted into the address of the first element of the array.

So I understand that the array name is returned like this.

```
int arr[10];
arr == &arr[0];
```

But if it is right, isn't it an *l-value* because the returned value is an address value?

Am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: An lvalue is a value that potentially designates i.e. *aliases* an object. A pointer is not an lvalue for the object it points to, you must follow the pointer i.e. dereference it

Comment: `arr` is an l-value. It decays to a pointer to it's first element in many contexts, but is an l-value.

Comment: You cannot change `&arr[0]` (ie, `arr = NULL;` is illegal). You can change the contents of the address `&arr[0]` (ie `*(&arr[0]) = 42;` (same as `arr[0] = 42;` or `*arr = 42;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was told that the array name is converted into the address of the first element of the array.

This applies as part of the evaluation of expressions in which the array's identifier appears, and there is a handful of exceptions.

> So I understand that the array name is returned like this.
>
> ```
> int arr[10];
> arr == &arr[0];
> ```

The automatic conversion to a pointer -- *when it occurs* -- is analogous to your expression `&arr[0]` (which in fact depends on that conversion in the first place), but it is incorrect to think of it as such a conversion being performed immediately and permanently when the array is declared.  An array's identifier identifies *the array*, not only its address or its first element.  In particular, the exceptions to the automatic conversion to a pointer factor in here, especially the fact that if `arr` is the identifier of an array, then `sizeof(arr)` evaluates to the size of that array, not the size of a pointer.

> But if it is right, isn't it an l-value because the returned value is an address value?

It is *not* right.  The reason that an array's identifier is an lvalue is that it designates the array.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2 Other operands)

> 1. ... **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type**, does not
>      have an incomplete type, does not have a
>      constqualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have
>      any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all 
>      contained aggregates or unions) with a constqualified type.

and

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus this expression statement

```
arr == &arr[0];
```

looks like

```
&arr[0] == &arr[0];
```

And according to this quote (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand....and **the
>   result is not an lvalue**.

That is in this expression statement

```
arr == &arr[0];
```

the non-modifiable lvalue of the type `int[10]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element (that is of the type `int *`) resulting in getting an rvalue.